# SQL hyperlink - SSMS comes back with multiple errors

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am new to SQL and I am teaching myself at home. I have been following a tutorial at home and, at the same time, I am trying to get creative. I am trying to link a hyperlink and I am keep getting an error.

Below is the code I found on a previous comment on Stack Overflow:

```
Medicalrecord Select CAST('https://www.google.com' as XML)
```

The idea is to create a chart with a column called "Medical records" and have a hyperlinked pdf to it.

Please find the full code below:

```
Create Table MedicalFiles
(
    PatientName varchar(50),
    DoctorName varchar(50),
    DoctorSpecialy varchar(50),
    reasonforthevisit varchar(50),
    doctorvisitcost int,
    medicationcost int,
    additionalcostsdescription varchar(50),
    Additionalcostvalue int,
    Medicalrecord Select CAST('https://www.google.com' as XML)
    )
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

> Msg 173, Level 15, State 13, Line 11 The definition for column
> 'Medicalrecord' must include a data type.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CREATE TABLE` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql) does not allow a `SELECT` query for a computed column definition. The DDL below will create a computed column with the XML constant so it can be used in SELECT queries:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MedicalFiles
(
    PatientName varchar(50),
    DoctorName varchar(50),
    DoctorSpecialy varchar(50),
    reasonforthevisit varchar(50),
    doctorvisitcost int,
    medicationcost int,
    additionalcostsdescription varchar(50),
    Additionalcostvalue int,
    Medicalrecord AS CAST('https://www.google.com' as XML)
);
```

Comment: everytime I add to my script, i hit save and execute, but everytime I execute the script I get an error because apparently SSMS trying to create a new table by re-executing the whole script. is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: the error is : Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'MedicalFiles' in the database.

Comment: @AnouarSeljouki, if you want to drop and recreate the table every time you run your script, add a conditional `DROP TABLE` before your `CREATE TABLE` statement. In newer SQL versions `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.MedicalFiles;`. Use an `IF` statement in older version like `IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MedicalFiles', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.MedicalFiles;`

Comment: I couldn't thank you enough for your continues support, however an answer brings a new question :). im gonna put each statement on a comment because I hit enter to skip a line and my comment gets posted

Comment: [Patient Name] varchar(50),
 [Doctor Name] varchar(50),
 [Doctor's Specialty] varchar(50),
 [reason for the visit] varchar(50),
 [Cost for Doctor's Visit] int,
 [medication cost] int,
 [additional costs description] varchar(50),
 [Additional costs Value] int,

Comment: as you can see on the script above, I made a minor modification. I added [ ] to create a space on the description, i click save and 'select top 1000 rows' to see the outcome and the following happens

Comment: This shows where the script was : /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP (1000) [PatientName]
      ,[DoctorName]
      ,[DoctorSpecialy]
      ,[reasonforthevisit]
      ,[doctorvisitcost]
      ,[medicationcost]
      ,[additionalcostsdescription]
      ,[Additionalcostvalue]
  FROM [MedicalFiles].[dbo].[MedicalFiles]

Comment: and no space gets created on my description

Comment: I understand you clicked save but you need to execute the script to make the changes to the database. Although SQL Server allows you to enclose identifiers that don't follow the rules, I suggest you name objects and columns to conform to the [rules for regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#rules-for-regular-identifiers) and alias as desired in the SELECT query or application for more user-friendly names.